# Different ways to fetch OAuth token from an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

*I know only two ways to get google OAuth token :*

**1.** [chrome.identity.getAuthToken()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) : Fetches token associated with chrome account. After restarting chrome, I can call `getAuthToken()` method without logging. Works great. But doesn't work for non - google account.

**2.** [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) : Works both for google and non- google account. But after restarting chrome, if call `launchWebAuthFlow()`, it asks for login again. It is annoying.

*What I want to achieve is to combine the functionalities of both :*

**Fetch OAuth token from both google and non-google account. And after restarting chrome, I can fetch token again without signing in.**

If anyone knows how to use `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()` to achieve the same or any other method??

Comment: I am surprised that this is about the only other place I can find reference to launchWebAuthFlow needing to start from scratch after a Chrome restart, which we are also seeing. Is it possible that it is an artifact of running an unpacked developer mode extension?

Comment: @lgaud I don't think so because i deployed my app on web store and faced the same issue. In case of chrome extensions launchWebAuthFlow() makes sense but it wasn't working like we wanted it to. So I ended up following a web app flow for OAuth 2.0 for my extension. In case you need help, feel free to ask me

Comment: FYI - I reached out to the Chromium team about the issue with launchWebAuthFlow clearing session state after login. This is known behavior: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721851#c8 . Feel free to comment on that ticket with your use case - I'm using Google login only (so Chrome login works for us) but I figure they could hear from others about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth providers will return some sort of reusable access token, which can be re-used on subsequent logins.  Usually these are very long-lived.  For example, dropbox returns an access token in the responseUrl (in the callback from the web flow), matching a regex pattern `/access_token=([^&]+)/`.

You can store this token in [local storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and access it on subsequent attempts without going through the auth flow again.

The auth tokens don't always live forever (or they could be manually deauthorized), so you have to watch out for 401 response code, and do the web auth flow again if that occurs.

Logic ends up quite complex, something like:

1. Get stored token
2. If no stored token, then launch web flow and save auth token in local storage
3. Try some operation using the stored token
4. if 401, then redo auth flow and retry operation

Comment: I know all about it. Actually my problem is regarding chrome API

Comment: same. store the chrome token. dont launch the flow again

Comment: My answer includes a link to the chrome api for storing data in local storage.

Comment: I can store the token in local storage, it expires after 1 hour so call launchWebAuthFlow() again and get the token without login prompt but when i restart chrome it asks for login. Shouldn't it store the login in cookies so that i dont have to enter my email and password everytime i restart chrome?

Comment: @Sid don't call the authflow again - just use the stored token.

Comment: But token gets expired after 1 hour so i have to call the webauthflow again.Main issue is that it should store the login when i restart chrome but it doesn't so it asks for password again

Comment: @Sid here is a link to some code that works for dropbox, hopefully it will help.  https://github.com/perfectapi/CKP/blob/develop/services/dropboxFileManager.js#L145-L197

Comment: Most of the access tokens are short lived(1 hour). I think you are talking about refresh token which is usable up to 30 days. I have used this refresh token to fetch access token in my web application. But chrome webAuthFlow doesn't seem to work with refresh token. I am going to try this again and report back.