# How to fetch Google OAuth access tokens from Chrome extensions - tradeoffs between options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-signin

**EDIT**: In case it helps others who find this, the fact that Gaia clears cookies after Chrome restart is known behavior. They recommend the use of Chrome login. See more [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721851&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=).

**The core question**: how do I fetch Google OAuth access tokens in the background from a Chrome extension without using the [getAuthToken method](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getAuthToken) in the chrome.identity API? This method forces users to login to Chrome, which isn't ideal for our app. There's also no way I can find to retrieve OpenID Connect ID tokens using the native methods exposed in the identity API.

Currently, I'm fetching tokens using the [launchWebAuthFlow method](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) from the chrome.identity API. This method launches an "Identity API Scope Approval UI" window in which the user makes the initial OAuth grant. This window (referred to as "gaia") has its own session / cookie data, separate from a browser session.

After the initial OAuth grant, the extension periodically retrieves access tokens in the background, and subsequently fetches data from Google APIs (e.g. Drive). This works well. When a user quits and re-opens Chrome, however, fetching access tokens fails - **gaia loses its session cookies when Chrome restarts, so running the launchWebFlowAuth method doesn't complete because Google can't authenticate the user** (unless we prompt the user to login in the Identity API Scope Approval UI again). [Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954876/different-ways-to-fetch-oauth-token-from-an-extension) seem to have had the same issue.

Google Sign-In would be ideal, but it [doesn't work in Chrome extensions](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/issues/102) (I'm getting the same "*Invalid cookiePolicy*" error as the author of that issue).

Any advice on how to best handle this use case would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Try using invoking the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) in silent mode, "the API will only return a token if the provider is able to provide a token without showing any UI. This is useful in cases when an app is doing the flow at app startup, for example, or in general in cases where there is no user gesture involved." Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - appreciate the help. I'm already passing the 'interactive': false flag to the launchWebAuthFlow method, as well as passing "prompt=none" to the Google OAuth URI, and that's working fine - requests for tokens are happening silently. On Chrome reboots, requests for token still happen silently - they just _fail_ silently, too, when gaia cookies are cleared.

Comment: "This method forces users to login to Chrome, which isn't ideal for our app." Can you explain why that is not ideal? Using a separate window to get them signed into their Google account is not a great experience either.

Comment: Logging into Chrome forces uses into a flow where they're asked about syncing data, etc., not just OAuth - that seems to heavy and some users are likely to abandon the install. Users can also only log into one Chrome account at a time, where our app needs to support multiple accounts. Asking people to create separate Chrome profiles to support that use case isn't ideal. Finally, as I mentioned, the chrome.identity API fails to support a method to retrieve ID tokens, which is required for specific features on our end.